# ¿Cómo obtener atributos de un objeto dentro de una lista de objetos en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente clase Registro donde puedo crear y verificar objetos del tipo Empleado:

```
#---Importe de clases---
import msvcrt
import os
import clases.empleado as registroE

class Registro():

    def registroEmpleado(self):
        os.system("cls")
        print("----------------------------------------------")
        print("    --- REGISTRO DE NUEVOS EMPLEADOS ---")
        codEmp = int(input("Código del empleado: "))
        #---Verifica si la ista está vacía.
        if lstEmpleado:
            #---Recorre cada objeto empleado en la lista.
            for empleados in lstEmpleado:
                #---Si se retorna un código de empleado ya registrado
                if registroE.Empleado.getCodEmp(empleados) == codEmp:
                    print(f"--- Ya existe un empleado registrado con el código {registroE.Empleado.getCodEmp(empleados)}. ---")
                    print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar, e intente nuevamente...")
                    break
                else:
                    nomEmp = input("Nombre del empelado: ")
                    print("TIPOS DE EMPLEADO:\n[1].-Vendedor\n[2].-Cajero\n[3].-Despachador")
                    tipEmp = int(input("Escriba el tipo de empleado a ser: "))
                    lstEmpleado.append(registroE.Empleado(codEmp, nomEmp, tipEmp))
                    print("--- El registro del nuevo empleado se ha realizado correctamente. ---")
                    print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar...")
                    break
        else:
            nomEmp = input("Nombre del empelado: ")
            print("TIPOS DE EMPLEADO:\n[1].-Vendedor\n[2].-Cajero\n[3].-Despachador")
            tipEmp = int(input("Escriba el tipo de empleado a ser: "))
            lstEmpleado.append(registroE.Empleado(codEmp, nomEmp, tipEmp))
            print("--- El registro del nuevo empleado se ha realizado correctamente. ---")
            print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar...")
        
        print(f"\n {lstEmpleado}")
        msvcrt.getch()
```

He creado 2 objetos Empleado, y el print de la lista de empleados me retorna lo siguiente:

```
 [111, Empleado 1, 1, 222, Empleado 2, 2]
```

Cuando intento verificar algún código de empleado nuevo, e intento con el código [111] me sale el error indicando que ya existe ese código en uso, pero por ejemplo, si intento hacerlo con el código [222] no me salta ningún error, y puedo seguir creando tantos Empleados con código [222] como mi memoria me lo permita. Lo que significa que no está iterando correctamente cada objeto dentro de la lista o no está retornando el código de empleado correctamente.

Mi pregunta es: **¿cómo podría iterar correctamente cada objeto en la lista para poder obtener su respectivo código?**

---

Clase modelo de Empleado:

```
class Empleado:
    def __init__(self, codEmp, nomEmp, tipEmp):
        self.codEmp = codEmp
        self.nomEmp = nomEmp
        self.tipEmp = tipEmp

    def getCodEmp(self):
        return self.codEmp
```

Comment: en primer lugar el append debe ir así `lstEmpleado.append([registroE.Empleado(codEmp, nomEmp, tipEmp)])` (entre corchetes el objeto)

Comment: Los acabo de añadir a cada .append, me guarda el primer objeto Empleado, pero para almacenar un segundo obtengo el error `'list' object has no attribute 'codEmp'`

Comment: Eee.... claramente pues no estas almacenado el objeto, tienes 2 opciones, almacenar el objeto o hacer un *truco* para la validación

Comment: ¿Cómo lo podría almacenar correctamente?

Comment: para mí, lo correcto sería almacenar la instancia del objeto y no su representación